# MYSQL Replace Statement using _ (UnderScore) or %

Tags: mysql, sql, string, amazon-web-services, sql-update

I need to Update a Column using Replace Query but I won't know 10 characters and i need to fill that up with _ just like in **LIKE** statements

```
UPDATE USERS SET LASTONLINE = REPLACE(LASTONLINE, "User1:__________", "User1:1620647000") WHERE NUMBER = '9988776655'
```

I'm trying to store timestamp of when the user was last online. I cannot change the table structure for many reasons which makes the question bigger. I just want to replace the old Timestamp which i won't know with the new one. I'm sure this can be done but having trouble with the logic. Any help is appreciated

Structure

```
NUMBER | LASTONLINE
9988.. | User1:<timestamp>,User2:<timestamp>
```

Comment: I'm lost.  If `lastonline` is a timestamp, why are you trying to set it to a string?  Sample data and desired results might help.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing multiple values in a string column is just not the SQL way to store data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a timestamp value, set it to a timestamp value.  For instance:

```
UPDATE USERS
    SET LASTONLINE = NOW()
    WHERE NUMBER = '9988776655';
```

I don't know *what* timestamp value you want to set it to.  This just uses the current time.

I have no idea why you are trying to set a timestamp to a string, but that won't do anything useful.

Comment: Because i have timestamps of multiple users in the same column. That's the reason i mentioned that the structure should remain the same

Comment: Have a look at the structure please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your LASTONLINE field contains a string of number of users1,2,3,4...
and from your example query you would know which user to update as well as the number being updated to, you can use subtring get the substring of string before the User (User1 in your case in your example), concatenate with desired string, and get the substring from the position of User1 plus 16 spaces which means string after the "User1: plus 10 digits").

```
  update USERS
        set LASTONLINE = concat(substring_index(LASTONLINE , 'User1:', 1),
                             'User1:1620647000',
                              substr(LASTONLINE,LOCATE('User1:',LASTONLINE)+16))
        where NUMBER = '9988776655';
```